# Wagon movement on completion of a feature

Tags: carcassonne

The rules for the Wagon state that when the feature it is placed on is completed, it can be move to an unclaimed, incomplete connected feature.  To my reading, this means that the feature it is moved to does not need to be *directly* connected to the feature just completed, as it does not explicitly say this.

However, in the [Annotated Rules](http://boardgamegeek.com/filepage/87531/carcassonne-standard-complete-annotated-rules), it says the wagon may only be moved to a feature directly connected.  I'm wondering how this conclusion is reached, and whether my interpretation of the rules in the box is valid?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are correct that the [English translation](http://zmangames.com/rulebooks/Carcassonne_Exp5.pdf) of the rule says nothing about direct:

> ...move it to a connected incomplete and unoccupied road, city or
>   monastery.

But this is just a (sadly typical) garbling of the [original German rules](http://www.hans-im-glueck.de/fileadmin/data_archive/Regeln/CarcErw5AbteiRegelWeb.pdf) which clearly state (emphasis added) that the feature must be directly connected

> ...oder in ein **direkt** angrenzendes Gebiet (Straße, Stadt oder Kloster)
>   versetzen.

So the conclusion in the Annotated Rules is reached by referring to the original German rules for the game. Your interpretation of the English rules is fair, but the rules in the box are (as is often the case with the English rules for Carcassonne) wrong.

Comment: Thanks.  The CAR usually covers these points - surprised there is no footnote for this!

Comment: @JamesThorpe: In general, if there's something in the CAR that conflicts with the English rules, it's safe to assume that's because the English translation is wrong.

Comment: I'll bear that in mind!

Answer (score 2):

It seems logical that the wagon can only move to a *directly* connected unclaimed feature, since the example in the Abbey & Mayor rulebook only depicts this scenario and the annotated rules emphasize it. [image: wagon]